# how to make dropdown box for iphone app

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

how can i add a dropdown box (html select tag) in my iPhone application?

Comment: the noise to signal ration seems to be increasing....

Comment: whats that? it isn't the answer of my question, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have a drop down list in the iphone.Instead of that it has the UIActionSheet.If you have more options like greater than 8 the UIActionSheet will have its own scroll and alert looks like table and the view will get an awesome look.Thats the only option we have.If you anything or if i am wrong just let me know
Thanks

Comment: I think you are talking about actionsheet. AlertView didn't show any table kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom combo box control. I have done this in one of my projects. You can do something like this. Create a ViewControlle with tableView in it. Make it's frame smaller. Add it's view on the view where you want to display combo. On tap of a button that looks like down arrow display tableView with some animation starting frame should just below the combo button.Hope it helps. First try this then if still you are unable to do let me know.